# After using save function for an eloquent model I got a wrong ID

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel

I am using Laravel 5.8 with SQL Server, and I have an issue with saving a new user.
After I save using an eloquent model and I try to get an ID, the value of the ID is wrong. For example, in my DB, the ID value is 57, but in the model, the value is 27.

Dump: (for this row in DB Id value is 57)

```
#attributes: array:6 
"Email" => "test@mail.com"
"Password" => "some_encrypted_value"
"Phone" => "+12312312312"
"UpdatedAt" => "2019-08-11 09:48:16.056"
"CreatedAt" => "2019-08-11 09:48:16.056"
"Id" => 27
```

Controller:

```
$user           = new UserModel();
$user->Email    = $body->email;
$user->Password = $this->encrypt($body->password);
$user->Phone    = $body->phone;
$user->save();
dump($user); // **Here $user->Id value is 27, but in DB the Id value is 57**
```

Model:

```
class UserModel extends Model {
    protected $table      = 'User';
    protected $primaryKey = 'Id';
    protected $keyType    = 'bigint';
}
```

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[User](
[Id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Username] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[Password] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
[Email] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
[Phone] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
[Activated] [bit] NULL,
[CreatedAt] [datetime] NULL,
[UpdatedAt] [datetime] NULL)
```

Comment: If it's an `IDENTITY`, why are you trying to assign the value of `ID`?

Comment: @Larnu I didn't try to assign any value for Id, I assign just email, password and phone.

Comment: Then why do you state `"Id" => 27` in your first block, but lead with *"(for this row in DB Id value is 57)"*?

Comment: How do you retrieve the data from database to dump?

Comment: @Larnu Is the dump result, after i saved the model.

Comment: @naneri After $user->save(), in $user->Id is a wrong value.

Comment: Are you 100% sure you're looking at the correct row, in the correct table, in the correct database? Sounds more like you are mixing up two rows rather than the model returning incorrect values.

Comment: I found the problem. On the User table I have a trigger that insert something in another table, and Laravel return last inserted Id in this connection not in this scope. Can i change somehow to return last inserted id in this table, not the one inserted by trigger?

Answer (score 1):

### EDIT

> I found the problem. On the User table I have a trigger that insert something in another table, and Laravel return last inserted Id in this connection not in this scope. Can i change somehow to return last inserted id in this table, not the one inserted by trigger?

### You've stumbled upon a true Laravel flaw

Unfortunately, there's no neat way to solve this as Laravel always gets the last insert id in mssql with the `@@IDENTITY` statement rather than with `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`. However, this horrendous code, from [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/scope-identity-in-eloquent?page=1), should do the trick:

```php
$user->save();
$tempQuery = $user->getConnection()->getPdo()->query("SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('User') AS id");
$user->Id = $tempQuery->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_OBJ)[0]->id;
```

I also could point you in another direction: Try changing the trigger itself. For example, what I could think now is to use something like `INSERT IGNORE` in your trigger so that the `last inserted id` gets persisted. If not enough, try googling solutions on that direction.

Hope it helps.

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER (not deleted because it's still valid):**

### Try removing the `protected $keyType` property from model.

```php
class UserModel extends Model {
    protected $table      = 'User';
    protected $primaryKey = 'Id';
}
```

I think you got the wrong idea about the `protected $keyType` property. **It is not meant** to receive the exact column type of your primary, but instead, it works along-side the `public $incrementing` property to help **Eloquent guess what will its behavior about IDENTITY be**.

In order words, if `protected $keyType` **is not defined as** `int` (default is int), Eloquent must probably be thinking it should be treated as a `string` and messing up somewhere.

Comment: With or without keyType, the problem persists. 
Now i fount that on the User table I have a trigger that insert something in another table, and Laravel return last inserted Id in this connection not in this scope.

Comment: Hello Sergiu, I updated the answer. See If i can help

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem. After a lot of research in my code, after insert record I insert another record into some table.
For this reason, eloquent return wrong ID.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).